# How to prevent Typescript from accepting different functions with the same signature

Tags: typescript, function, types

Lets say we have two different functions that have the same signature. If you define a third functions that accepts on of the functions you can pass in any function with the same signature.

```
type A = (a: string) => void;
type B = (b: string) => void;

const a = (a: string) => {}
const b = (b: string) => {}

function C(func: A) {
    // ...
}

C(a);
C(b);
```

How to prevent Typescript from accepting b?

Comment: Can you explain your use case?  With enough effort you could get behavior *like* this, such as with branding ([example](https://tsplay.dev/NnX4dW))... but I don't see the point.

Comment: Both `A` and `B` are the same thing, though. Remember that TS uses structural typing, so in either case you have a function that takes a string and returns void. You could use something like branding but ultimately it seems like a design problem - if you want to *restrict* the functions such that even though two cover the required signatures, one is deemed unfit, that seems like an API that you have to jump through hoops to just use.

Comment: The thing is that if I have two different classes A and B I would not be able to pass the object instance of the class to function C unless it was of class type A. It's more of a theoretical example without a specific use case.

Comment: *Classes* are a lot more different than functions. It's *possible* that structural typing might allow two distinct classes to be used interchangeably, however, I would say that in most practical code that's very rarely going to be the case. If you have classes that seem to be *exactly the same* yet should be distinct, I'd first look if they need to be 1. Classes 2. Distinct. Often it might turn out that the answer is "no" and they might indeed be interchangeable. Or maybe you need to differentiate them more. It's hard to say in a theoretical situation.